# nginx is redirecting subdomain into parent domain

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect, proxypass

I am trying to setup GitLab in subdomain.example.com. But when calling this url, it is getting redirected into www.example.com. Following is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/subdomain.example.com file. I followed this [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/development/version-control/how-to-unbundle-nginx-from-omnibus-gitlab-for-serving-multiple-websites).

```
upstream gitlab {
            server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    server_tokens off; 
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

    client_max_body_size 250m;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
}
```

### Nginx access logs

```
172.217.26.206 - - [21/Oct/2017:00:50:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
172.217.26.206 - - [21/Oct/2017:00:56:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
172.217.26.206 - - [21/Oct/2017:00:57:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

What's wrong in this configuration.

Comment: There are no errors in the results of "nginx -T" command.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the access logs showing an example request, particularly with the response code. It might be interesting to see what the same request sent directly to the gitlab server returns as well.

Comment: Added log entries. @Tim

Comment: My best guess is the 302 redirect is coming back from gitlab, as there's no obvious reason Nginx would send a 302. I think you'll have to look through various logs and config files to try to work out what's going on.

Comment: Have you made the symbolic link from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/subdomain.example.com` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/subdomain.example.com` and restarted nginx?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case of the configuration file not being read by nginx. Reload or restart nginx to have the configuration file read by nginx.